# Specified type 'google_ads_failure' does not exist in Google Ads API v8

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client

I have two issues:

I'm calling G-Ads API to bulk remove ads ([code](https://github.com/google/bowling-compliance-ads-remover/blob/main/src/main.py#L440))

```
for error_detail in error_details:
            # Retrieve an instance of the google_ads_failure class from the client
            failure_message = gAdsServiceWrapper.client.get_type("google_ads_failure")
            # Parse the string into a google_ads_failure message instance.
            # To access class-only methods on the message we retrieve its type.
            google_ads_failure = type(failure_message)
            failure_object = google_ads_failure.deserialize(error_detail.value)

            for error in failure_object.errors:
                # Construct and print a string that details which element in
                # the above ad_group_operations list failed (by index number)
                # as well as the error message and error code.
                print("A partial failure at index "
                      f"{error.location.field_path_elements[0].index} occurred "
                      f"\nError message: {error.message}\nError code: "
                      f"{error.error_code}")
                index_array.append(error.location.field_path_elements[0].index)
                error_array.append({"error_message": error.message, "error_code": error.error_code})
```

1. I get a partial error
2. And the code fails to parse it (taken form the official [website](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/handle-partial-failure?hl=uk#python))

My terminal shows:

Partial failures occurred. Details will be shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\bowling\venv\lib\site-packages\google\ads\googleads\client.py", line 426, in get_type
    message_class = getattr(type_classes, name)
  File "D:\projects\bowling\venv\lib\site-packages\google\ads\googleads\v8\__init__.py", line 1753, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"unknown type {name!r}.")
AttributeError: unknown type 'google_ads_failure'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\bowling\src\main.py", line 535, in <module>
    main(args.top_id)
  File "D:\projects\bowling\src\main.py", line 141, in main
    removed_ads_count = remove_disapproved_ads_for_account(account)
  File "D:\projects\bowling\src\main.py", line 206, in remove_disapproved_ads_for_account
    remove_ads(ad_removal_operations, ads_to_remove_json, account_id)
  File "D:\projects\bowling\src\main.py", line 300, in remove_ads
    index_array, error_array = _print_results(response_chunk)
  File "D:\projects\bowling\src\main.py", line 439, in _print_results
    failure_message = gAdsServiceWrapper.client.get_type("google_ads_failure")
  File "D:\projects\bowling\venv\lib\site-packages\google\ads\googleads\client.py", line 428, in get_type
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Specified type 'google_ads_failure' does not exist in Google Ads API v8
```

Answer (score 0):

failure_message = gAdsServiceWrapper.client.get_type("google_ads_failure")

I think this should be -
failure_message = gAdsServiceWrapper.client.get_type("GoogleAdsFailure")